# Elasticsearch avoid maxClauseCount by refactoring bool match clauses

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I have an `elasticsearch` query that uses a lot of `match` clauses (around 1300) since I have a very large data set. ES throws an error saying this:

```
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "too_many_clauses",
        "reason": "too_many_clauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
}
```

I did some research online and found that it is not a good practice to increase the `maxClauseCount`. Some from `elastic` mentioned that I should rewrite my queries as a `terms` query rather than `bool`. Here is an example of my query. How do I rewrite it so that I don't hit `maxClauseCount`?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "city": "dallas"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "city": "london"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "city": "singapore"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "city": "prague"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "city": "ontario"
          }
        },
        ...........................................
        ...........................................
        ...........................................
      ]
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Switching a match query to a term(s) query is only OK if your search is using exact matches, and not analyzed matches (a term query is case sensitive, etc...). If that is the case, indeed, this is an easy way to diminish the number of clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "city": [
              "prague",
              "london",
              "chicago",
              "singapore",
              "new york",
              "san francisco",
              "mexico city",
              "baghdad"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```